# Remove ad tag from div before it is called

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design

I am trying to put together a responsive design, where certain ad calls would not be used at given media queries.

One way that was suggested is to put the ad call in a div, and then use jquery to remove the contents of the div (the ad call) if window.matchMedia is a given size.

So I put together [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/smlombardi/3zZuH/) as proof of concept, but, as you can see the ad gets called anyway.  Here I did not address the media query at all yet, just trying to prevent the ad call.

Anyone know how I might accomplish this, or is this idea flawed and there's a better mthod.

Comment: *Remove ad tag from div before it is called*: you might argue that in that case there is nothing to remove.

Comment: @Kooilnc is right - can you wrap the ad script in a condition so that it only runs given your condition?  That would be a much cleaner solution than adding something via script, then removing it via script...

Comment: I don't know if you can remove something before it is called since if it is not called then there is nothing to remove

Comment: How about doing it the other way? - insert the tag only if there is no media match

Comment: The issue is this:   I have 3 ad calls, one for each desktop, ipad, iphone. I have 3 divs (since we need to specify different locations in the responsive design, e.g. a top-right-rail ad would drop to the bottom when iPad sized).  I need to, depending on my media event listener code, write valid ad call to the "current" container div and not to the other 2, leaving them empty.

We were thinking it would be easier to just write the ad tags as usual to all 3, then disable the 2 that don't currently apply to that media query.

Answer (score 0):

Why not let the ad calls fire as normal and then set display:none on the container divs for specific media queries:

```
@media only screen and (min-width:0px) and (max-width:319px) { 

.the-ad-i-want-to-hide {display:none;}

}
```

Comment: because the ad gets called still and probably gets an impression which I think he wants to avoid.

Comment: Ya, that is the only downfall to this approach.  The analytics will still fire even though the ad is hidden.

Comment: yes, I don't think we can avoid that using jquery... should really be done on the ad itself or on the server level so it does not get called if the conditions are not met

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  Can't just hide it since an impression is generated anyway. And doing it server side requires 2 trips to the server (one to get the window size, then send it back to get correct code). The people at Doubleclick said not to do that, that there should be a way using Media Event Listeners... which is what I'm trying to decipher.